# Fibonacci sequence works in python, but not in c?

Tags: python, c, fibonacci

I have the following python code:

```
a, b = 1, 1
for i in range(0, 100):
    print a
    a, b = b, a + b
```

It generates this:
1
1
2
3
5
8
etc

I wrote the same in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
long long unsigned int a = 1, b = 1;
void main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        printf("%llu \n", a);
        a = b, b = a + b;
    }
}
```

It generates this:
1
1
2
4
8
16
32
etc

Why does the c program generate powers of 2 when it is using the exact same operations?

Comment: The comma operator does something different in C than in Python.

Comment: Also If `long long unsigned` is 64 bits, overflow occurs at 93th(0 origin) in C. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/0dtkQI)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

in python packs the values `b` and `a + b` into a tuple, then unpacks it back into `a` and `b`.

C does not supports that feature, but rather use the comma to separate between assignments, so `a = b, b = a + b` get translated as

```
a = b;
b = a + b;
```

where `b` gets doubled every time because the assignment is not simultaneous.

To fix that you'd have to assign each variable separately:

```
b = a + b;
a = b - a; // a + b - a = b
```

Comment: Your C translation is wrong, if it had been correct then it wouldn't had generated power of 2...

Comment: @NeilSlater I mean `a = b, b = a + b;` is not translated as `a; b = b; a + b;`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès thanks, I used the python version for the analysis, fixed

Answer (score 3):

Because `,` has different meanings in C and python. In python:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

means modify `a` and `b` (simultaneously) with respective values `b` and `a+b`.

While in C:

```
 a = b, b = a + b;
```

means do `a=b` and then after `b=a+b`.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52550/7076153).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uintmax_t a = 1, b = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%" PRIuMAX "\n", a);
        b = a + b;
        a = b - a;
    }
}
```